# Не могу передать данные из одного php в другой

Tags: php

Делаю видео сайт, необходимо в стандартный post запрос с id добавить значение своего поля test, чтобы в результате к описанию видео добавилось значение моего поля test.

Как только не пробовал, ничего своего добавить в запрос к **ajax.php** не могу, соответственно и в ajax.php получить значение для test тоже.

Пытался данные в базу отправлять, в базе, в таблице videos создал поле test.
Потом test решил прописывать сразу в описание `'$video_details'`, так `'$test $video_details'` - получилось, но только если значение test прописать в самом ajax.php, передать значение не могу.

Все перепробовал, неделю вожусь, встал на этой задаче, дальше идти не получается.
Помогите, пожалуйста.

```
      <div class="form-group">
      <label>Test</label>
      <input type="text" name="test" class="form-control" placeholder="Test" value="<?php if (isset($test)) {echo urldecode($test);} ?>" />
      </div>
```

**Файл videos.php** отправляет данные к ajax.php https://ideone.com/2711op

**Файл ajax.php** получает данные от videos.php https://ideone.com/cNSR45

Answer (score 2):

Сделайте следующие:

На кнопку вешаете

```
<div onclick="javascript:send('Значение, Значение2');">Отправить</div>
```

добавляете скрипт

```
function send(text, text2) {
    var idtext = text;
    var idtext2 = text2;
 // можно просто получить значение input 
 // var input = $('input.form-control').val();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'send.php',
        data: "idtext=" + idtext + "&idtext2=" + idtext2,
        success: function(result) {
   //тут выводите ваш результат
   //можно так $("#result").html(result);
        }
    })
}
```

И сам файл send.php

```
<? if(isset($_POST["idtext"])) 
{ 
$idtext = $_POST['idtext'];
$idtext2 = $_POST['idtext2']; 
}
?>
```

Comment: Сейчас попробую, спасибо!

Comment: Нет, там нет смысла в этом, свободно отправляются значения, пример, `id=oSAn42zalps&category=1&action=import_single_youtube_video` https://i.gyazo.com/c960f2a7f683b94501a85155a77ff039.png Однако свой test туда добавить не получается. Если быть точнее, я даже не понял, где в videos.php идет отправка данных именно при добавлении видео. Пытался добавить везде, где мог, не получилось.

Comment: я так понял этот код не ваш, вы уверены что он вообще рабочий?

Comment: так туда данные передаются не POST а GET, $id = abs(intval(make_safe(xss_clean($_GET['id']))));

Comment: Да, код не мой, но он рабочий. Есть две возможности загрузить видео, каждое по отдельности и списком. Код указанный вами отвечает за редактирование и удаление $id = abs(intval(make_safe(xss_clean($_GET['id']))))

Comment: кстати а где сам JS скрипт? в коде его нет, отправка href="javascript:void();" data-toggle="ajax-modal" data-url="ajax.php?case=video_details&id=<?php echo $item['id']['videoId']; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $item['snippet']['thumbnails']['medium']['url']; ?>"

Comment: в нем как раз вы должны добавить свое новое значение

Comment: JS там нет, в вашей ссылке я уже добавлял свое значение так href="javascript:void();" data-toggle="ajax-modal" data-url="ajax.php?case=video_details&test=test&id=<?php echo $item['id']['videoId']; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $item['snippet']['thumbnails']['medium']['url']; ?>" В запросе нет test

Comment: ну по идее должен  приниматься в строке 370 если написать $test = make_safe($_POST['test']);

Comment: если даже в запросе не передается, значит где то стоит проверка на определенные значения, остальные удаляет, мне кажется в этой строке $case = make_safe(xss_clean($_GET['case']));
$action = make_safe(xss_clean($_POST['action']));

Comment: нужно посмотреть функции make_safe и xss_clean что они делают

Comment: В том-то и дело, что даже не отправляется. Сейчас поищу проверку на отправляемые данные.

Answer (score 1):

Если вы хотите обратиться методом POST из формы  то смотрите документацию http://htmlbook.ru/html/form атрибут action.

Comment: Я знаю как отправлять post, в примере не стал засорять оригинал своим кодом. Просто добавил само поле test для видимости. Документацию на всякий случай прочту т.к. отправить у меня в итоге не получается, да и принять тоже. Спасибо!